# What's the difference between 'How somebody can...'? and 'How can somebody...'?

Tags: difference, modal-verbs, questions

For example:

> How can she get to the bank.

or

> How she can get to the bank

What's the difference? Which one is correct?

Comment: The short answer is going to be "The second sentence is wrong, and a common mistake made by people learning English". Please have a look our our English Language Learners site.

Comment: I think so, but I don't know why the answer to my practice exercise told me the second was correct

Comment: Sorry, the original is 'Sally asked how she could get to the bank', I misread it.

Comment: That's an entirely different kind of sentence.  I strongly recommend you check out our [ell.se] site.

Comment: To get a correct answer, you must edit your question as you have stated it in the comments, or I could edit it for you.

Comment: Now it's too late to change meaning of the question, as it got already answers. *Sally asked how she could get to the bank.* is a correct sentence, which is different from *How can she get to the bank.*

Answer (score 2):

**How can she get to the bank** is a question.  It cannot be part of a larger sentence like "Sally asked how can she get to the bank", because it is in question order.

**How she can get to the bank** is a phrase.  It cannot be a sentence by itself, but it could be a part of a sentence like "This is *how she can get to the bank*" or "I don't know *how she can get to the bank*."

You might find it helpful to review [how to form wh- questions in English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/questions-wh-questions).

Answer (score 0):

How **can she** get to the bank?- simple question

If a question ('How can she get to the bank?') is part of a long sentence, the question loses its normal question word order.

Can you tell me how **she can** get to the bank? Do you know how **she can** get to the bank? I know how **she can** get to the bank.